Trying to allow a user to download an image from .NET Minimal API, but it keeps getting corrupted
I am making a web application with a Vue.js frontend and a .NET Minimal API backend. One of the features is allowing users to download an image exposed by the API. However, the image that gets downloaded is corrupted and can't be viewed. The image is still in proper condition on the back end, so the corruption happens somewhere in between. I think it may have something to do with a mime type or casting - but I'm having trouble testing to figure it out.
Here's the exposed endpoint for the image:
app.MapGet("/documents", async () =>
        {
            var mimeType = "image/png";
            var path = @$"sampleimage.png";

            return Results.File(Path.GetFullPath(path), contentType: mimeType);
        });

Here's the function that grabs the image:
async getDocuments() {
    return await this.get<File>("/documents", {}, {});
  }

Here's the code that I use to create the download link.
const getDocuments = () => {
  UploadDocumentsClient.getDocuments()
    .then((resp) => {
      //console.log(resp);

      const link = document.createElement('a');

      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([resp], {type: "image/png"})
      );

      link.setAttribute('download', "sampleimage.png");
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click(); 
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error("unable to get documents" + e);
    }); 
};

I would like the getDocuments function to download a working image file, rather than a corrupted one that does not load. I have tried it with several different images and none of them have come out properly. This function works with text files, so it is almost there, but I can't get it to work with .png.

Just tested the API with postman, and figured out that the image turns out great when grabbing directly from the endpoint. I think it might be the way I've cast it as Vue grabs it?

Welcome to SO, Levi.
